# How can I print duplicate items from an OrderedDict?

Tags: dictionary, exception, ordereddict

My `OrderedDict` contains 5 key value pairs which result in the word, `"Belle"`. Every letter its own key with values starting from 1 through 5, from left to right, `B = 1`, `e = 2`, etc. Printing this `OrderedDict` returns only 3 letters, `B`, `l` and `e`. Notice, it doesn't print the repeated `e` and `l`s.
In the code below, I use a `for` statement to print `"Belle"` so it can print vertically. My goal is to print the complete word `"Belle`" vertically, with each letter as a key with its value pair.

```
text6 = OrderedDict({'B':1, 'e':2, 'l':3, 'l':4, 'e':5})
for key, value in text6.items():
    print(key, value)
```

Code above returns:

```
B 1
e 5
l 4
```

Desried output:

```
B 1
e 2 
l 3
l 4
e 5
```

Comment: Dictionaries cannot have multiple entries with the same key. If you `print(text6)` you'll see this: `OrderedDict([('B', 1), ('e', 5), ('l', 4)])`, when you specify the same key multiple times only the last value ends up in the dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asking a `dict` (including `OrderedDict`) to do what you are asking it to do is impossible. A `dict` of any type can only contain unique keys. All subsequently added pre-existing keys will overwrite the key and reset it's value.

In order to get the output you want to see, we can use a different data structure. In this implementation, we utilize a `list` which will contain a `tuple` for each (value, index) pair we will get by iterating through  "Belle" using `enumerate`

```
list((v, i) for i, v in enumerate("Belle", 1))
```

Comment: @mj_codec: Note that dictionaries (as well as `OrderedDict`s) have been ordered in Python since version 3.7 — except for a few subtle differences they are virtually identical nowadays.

Comment: I took that tidbit out. Thanks martineau. By the way I thought it was 3.6 which brought that change.

Comment: It was implemented in CPython in version 3.6, but wasn't made part of the Python language specification until 3.7.